# SWTOR: Sound has completely stopped working

Tags: technical-issues, star-wars-the-old-republic

I started the launcher for SWTOR today. It took a moment to initialize, as if there was a patch, but a much shorter amount of time, and no install time whatsoever. I found that odd, but I didn't think much of it. I started the game and no sound can be heard at all. I thought it was my computer at first. This took very little time to verify. It's just SWTOR. The sound in game preferences is active, the sound on the mixer is fine, my sound drivers should be up to date. I've restarted the computer, I've restarted the game several times, I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try pressing Alt+S while logged into a character.

Comment: You can also try a Repair from the Settings menu in the launcher (log into the launcher but don't launch the game, and go into the username drop-down at the top-right).